# Android asks me to declare a final to a value I want to use more than once in a function onclicklistner

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

(Already checked the other question, this one is firebase related)
Hello, so I am trying to repeatedly use a ref inside onClicklistner, but android studio asks me to declare a value as final, hence it only retrieves one item from the firebase.. This is my code which will show more details

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bathrooms");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                for ( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                    final Bathrooms bathrooms = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Bathrooms.class); // this is where I am asked and forced to create a final.

                    if( bathrooms.getAvailability().equals("Yes")) {


                        bathroomsArrayList.add(bathrooms);


                    }


                Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if(bathroomsArrayList!=null) {

                            if (bathrooms.getFloor().equals(Floor.getSelectedItem()) &&bathrooms.getSection().equals(Section.getSelectedItem())) {
                                    disable.setChecked(true);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Browse done successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }

                            else {
                                disable.setChecked(false);
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No bathrooms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            disable.setChecked(false);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "array empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }

                    }
                });



                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



return rootview;

    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with being `final`?

Answer (score 0):

guy.
the first way and actually the easiest one, I use in this situations, is to define your variable before onCreate(),
then you can use it at every void you want.
think it helps you...

Comment: Thank you for replying, I  can't do that as I need the snapshot from the database reference, so it most inside

Comment: @OmarBinAli What exactly you want to do here? Android ask for final if you are using var inside on-click listener and the var is not declarered  before on create, and i think a ref can be final withpout any problem, because you can't change the value of ref at all, the final means that once its valued is set so you can't set another value to this var,

Comment: hi thanks for replying, I want to check the entire firebase for a certain value "availability=yes" and then turn the togglebutton, what happens I only retrive one value ( the last added) from the firebase and not everything.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine why AndroidStudio would force you to final here. Suggesting maybe.
Anyways, since the variable is defined inside the for loop it will be created newly with each iteration anyways, so it is fine for it to be final -- i.e. it is initialized directly when it is created and is never assigned a new value.

TL;DR: If your code is not working as expected, it is not the variable being final.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I don't see any other reason why the code wouldn't function, because what I want is for the array to contain all the values meanwhile it only brings one value ( the last added to the firebase)

Comment: You should debug your code and see how many children dataSnapshot.getChildren() returns. And debug the for loop to see what is going on.